# Abot Web Crawler Performance

Tags: c#, .net, web-crawler, screen-scraping

I have built a robots.txt crawler which extracts the urls out of robots and then loads the page with some post processing once the page is done. This all happens quite fast, and I can extract information from 5 pages per second.

In the event a website doesn't have a robots.txt I use Abot Web Crawler instead. The problem is Abot is far slower than the direct robots.txt crawler. It seems when Abot hits a page with lots of links, it schedules each link very slowly. With some pages taking 20+ seconds to queue all and run the post process as mentioned above.

I use the PoliteWebCrawler which is configured to not crawl external pages. Should I instead be crawling multiple websites at once or is there another, faster solution to Abot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added a patch to Abot to fix issues like this one. Should be available in nuget version 1.5.1.42. See [issue #134](https://github.com/sjdirect/abot/issues/135) for more details. Can you verify this fixed your issue?

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that the site you are crawling cannot handle lots of concurrent requests? A quick test would be to open a browser and start clicking around the site while Abot is crawling it. If the browser is noticeably slower then the server is showing signs of the load.

If that is the issue, you need to slow the crawl down through the configuration settings.

If not, can you give a url of a site or page that is being crawled slowly? Abot's full configuration would also be helpful.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the help. The crawl config is pretty simple:
`this.crawlConfig.CrawlTimeoutSeconds = 0;
this.crawlConfig.IsExternalPageCrawlingEnabled = false;`

The site is domain.com.au and I wouldn't say the site is slow. The sitemap crawler which I've written is separate from Abot and is really fast, scanning around 5 pages per second (minimum).

Abot is only slow on pages like this one: http://www.domain.com.au/real-estate/buy/nsw/ which takes 20+ seconds to do a scan.